# .htaccess some folders to subfolder/folders

Tags: .htaccess

About .htaccess I will like to do following

**www.domain.com** go to this folder **www_folder**
url in browser **www.domain.com**

**www.domain.com/yyy** go to this folder **www_folder/yyy/**
url in browser  **www.domain.com/yyy**

And i will like
**www.domain.com/abc** go to this folder **www_folder/xxx/abc**
url in browser **www.domain.com/abc**

**www.domain.com/def** go to this folder **www_folder/xxx/def**
url in browser **www.domain.com/def**

I will not show folder **xxx** in the browser url.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `www_folder` is what your http server's host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` points to all you'd have to do is rewrite the URLs `/abc` and `/def`, since `/` and `/yyy` should already do what you ask. So what is left are these two rewriting rules to get implemented:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?abc$ /xxx/abc [END]
RewriteRule ^/?def$ /xxx/def [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).